# how to compare dates using relational Operators in dart?

Tags: string, date, flutter, dart

I'm working on a problem which requires to compare the date with other if the selected date is less than given then print Hello.

The date is present In String Format like given in Examaple
Ex:

```
if('2020-1-13'<'2021-1-5')
{
print(hello);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this it should work

`````
````
var date1 = DateTime.parse('2020-01-13').millisecondsSinceEpoch.toInt();
var date2 = DateTime.parse('2021-01-15').millisecondsSinceEpoch.toInt();
if(date1 < date2){
    print('true');
}else{
    print('false');
}
````
`````

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing that just use the date's `isBefore` or `isAfter` operator

It would look something like the following:

```
final now = DateTime.now();
final yesterday = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1));
print(now.isAfter(yesterday));  //true
```

Since your dates are in STring format, it you would have to use the [DateTime.parse()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html) method to construct your date objects, and then use the operators talked about above

Comment: @Creator If this solved your problem please hit the green check mark to upvote. Thanks!

Comment: What if both dates are the same? We can't use these functions when dates are the same.

Comment: Why not, they would both return false, and if you wanted to test if they were equal you would use now.getTime() == yesterday.getTime().

Answer (score 0):

[`package:basics`](https://pub.dev/packages/basics) provides [`DateTime` extensions](https://pub.dev/packages/basics) that can easily compare `DateTime` objects.

(Disclosure: I contributed those particular extensions.)